# Sending image file via HTTP post prepends unwanted characters to the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, postman

I'm trying to send a simple image file to a lambda function. Once it gets to the function I need to turn it into a buffer and then manipulate it. Right now when data is received there are a bunch of characters prepended to the data:

```
"body": "--X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"americanflag.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n�PNG\r\n\n\rIHDR0�\b�;BIDATx��]u|����{g��.H\b^h�F)PJ�������Www﫻P���\"E��$!nk3���3�l���{��=�L�����=��=�|)����ٿ)��\"�$��q�����\r���'s��4����֦M��\"C�y��*U�YbUEc����|�ƼJ���@�=�/ �6���OD�p�����[�Q�D��\b�<hheB��&2���}�F�*�1M�u������BR�%\b�1RD�Q�������Q��}��R )%ĉ�Idv�݌髝�S��_W�Z�xSaZ��p�5k�{�|�\\�?
```

I have no idea how to handle that. My plan has just been to create a buffer as you normally would in Node:`Buffer.from(data, 'utf8')`. But it's throwing an error

**Things I've tried:**
I've been testing the function with Insomniac and Postman, both with the same result.

- I've gone with both a `multipart/form` and `binary file` for the body
  of the request.
- I've tried multiple image files.
- I've set the header of content-type to image/png and other file
  types.
- I've removed the headers.

I know that I could upload the files to S3 and that would be much easier but it negates the point of what I'm writing. I don't want to store the images I just want to manipulate them and then discard them.

This is what the response looks like when I send it back to myself.

**Edit:** The full code is uploaded. Again, I'm not sending via node at this very moment. It's simply through Postman/Insomniac. If the answer is simply "write your own encoder" then please put that as an answer.

[image]

Comment: you need to show how your attempting to encode that file.

Comment: I posted an answer, please let me know is it helpful to you or not?

Comment: Right now I'm just attaching it through the Postman/Insomniac interface. I have written a single line of code for attaching

Comment: Then at least try out yourself or with an answer and let me know.

Comment: I'm definitely going to, gimme a sec

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not upload full code so based on my best prediction I post an answer here. There are probably any of the solutions may help to you.

Encoding Base64 Strings:

```
'use strict';
let data = '`stackoverflow.com`';  
let buff = new Buffer(data);  
let base64data = buff.toString('base64');    
console.log('"' + data + '" converted to Base64 is "' + base64data + '"');
```

Decoding Base64 Strings:

```
'use strict';
let data = 'YHN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tYA==';  
let buff = new Buffer(data, 'base64');  
let text = buff.toString('ascii');
console.log('"' + data + '" converted from Base64 to ASCII is "' + text + '"');
```

Encoding binary data to base64 string:

```
'use strict';    
const fs = require('fs');    
let buff = fs.readFileSync('image-log.png');  
let base64data = buff.toString('base64');    
console.log('Image converted to base 64 is:\n\n' + base64data);
```

Decoding Base64 Strings to Binary Data:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
let data = 'encoded binary  string';
let buff = new Buffer(data, 'base64');  
fs.writeFileSync('image-log.png', buff);
console.log('Base64 image data converted to file: image-log.png');
```

Base64 encoding is the way to converting binary data into plain ASCII text. It is a very useful format for communicating between one or more systems that cannot easily handle binary data, like images in HTML markup or web requests.

In Node.js the Buffer object can be used to encode and decode Base64 strings to and from many other formats, allowing you to easily convert data back and forth as needed.

Comment: (Advice for future posts: please use the quote device `>` for things that are actually quotes, e.g. excerpts from manuals, other posts on Stack Overflow or elsewhere on the web, speeches, talks, computer output, etc. It is not a general highlighter. Thanks).